# jQuery Slide-Up is coming from either bottom left or bottom right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to work out why my slide-up footer menu ... It should be coming straight up, but instead is either coming up from the bottom left corner or bottom right corner, depending on whether the `left: 0` or `right: 0` is removed from the `.footerbar` css.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. It's annoying the hell out of me. :-(

This is where I'm currently at...

```js
$('#footerNav').addClass('slide-down');

function openNav() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footerNav').toggle(function() {
      if ($('#footerNav').hasClass('slide-up')) {
        $('#footerNav').addClass('slide-down', 1000);
        $('#footerNav').removeClass('slide-up');
      } else {
        $('#footerNav').removeClass('slide-down');
        $('#footerNav').addClass('slide-up', 1000);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.footerbar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.footerbar a:hover,
.footerbar a:focus {
  color: #046B86;
}

.footerbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  bottom: -60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onClick="openNav()">footer tray</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id="footerNav" class="footerbar">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you are adding `slide-up` and `slide-down` class but I can't see it in your css code..

Comment: What is your style for slide-up/down classes? Any particular reason why you use this with addClasses and not jQuery method .slideUp()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing it to only use .slideUp(), it worked without fault. (Takes someone else to shed light on it).

Thanks for the suggestion!